# in PyQt5 move tab page widgets to desired tab page dynamically using tab index

Tags: python-3.x

In python, using PyQt5 while moving from one tab page to another, need to move the widgets from source page to destination tab page using the index number.

I was trying the following code. But No idea. Can anybody guide me. Thanks

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

```
class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1251, 645)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 40, 1161, 571))
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")

        self.tab_1 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_1.setObjectName("tab_1")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_1, "")

        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tabWidget.currentChanged.connect(self.header_Tab_Changed)

        global TAB_OPTION
        if TAB_OPTION==0:
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_1)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 130, 631, 161))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        elif TAB_OPTION==1:
            self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.tab_2)
            self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(100, 100, 431, 61))
            self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)
    def header_Tab_Changed(self,index):
        global TAB_OPTION
        TAB_OPTION=index
        #I need to move the push button between tabs ????????????????
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_1), _translate("Form", "First-Page"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "Second-Page"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    global TAB_OPTION
    TAB_OPTION=0
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: do you want the button to physically move or just recreated?

Comment: Physically move ---- Basically I want to manage all tab pages with same widgets as per choice. so that i can minimize the number of widgets and screen management will be easier. Thank you very much